# Simple side drawer issue in android

Tags: android

I implemented my left slide drawer for menu options using Simple-side-drawer Library. Its working fine but the issue is, the drawer layout menu options are responding to onclick events even after my drawer is closed state ie (menu options responding to onclick events from my MainActivity).

Comment: what you have tried post your code..

Comment: That's magic. No one can help you until you post possible code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check SimpleSideDrawer's isClosed() method to make sure if it is closed.

```
SimpleSideDrawer menuDrawerLeft = new SimpleSideDrawer( this );
menuDrawerLeft.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_drawer_left);        

final Button buttonInLeftDrawer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonInLeftDrawer);    
buttonInLeftDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if (menuDrawerLeft.isClosed()) {return;}

        //runs only when the drawer is open 

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code it's hard to give any suggestions.

One advice though. Are you using this library:

https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer

If so, please consider using the built-in Navigation Drawer that Google has released instead. It follows the design guidelines (which Simple Side Drawer does not) and is well tested to work.

See these resources for your implementation:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Yes ,I am using https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer Library.  I can use the built in Navigation Drawer,in this case the whole implementation of my project has to be changed. I was struggling to find the bug since last few days

Comment: I would recommend you to go with the standard implementation for a number of reasons. Here's a tutorial on how to get started and how to generate custom graphics for it:

1: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1793
2: https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/9uPhkxoucpj

Comment: @user3056097, did you try the built in Navigation Drawer?